# Values of Array in C initialized to 0 past array size index

Tags: c, arrays

Why does this code print out b[index]: 0 all the way up until 1011, than at 1012 starts producing garbage?

```
int b[10];
for(int i=0; i<1025; i++){
    printf("b[%d]: %d\n", i, b[i]);
}
```

The output I get is:

```
b[0]: 0
b[1]: 0
...
b[1011]: 0
b[1012]: 1376789009
b[1013]: 0
b[1014]: 2036613137
```

Comment: Undefined behaviour means anything can happen, including stuff appearing to work in some defined way.

Comment: Anything past `b[9]` is _undefined behavior_.  What did you expect to happen after that?

Comment: I expected garbage to be output for all the values after b[9], but it is consistently 0 up until b[1011], and then the numbers output at higher indexes are consistently the same as well, which is what surprised me.

Comment: Why `0` isn't a garbage value?

Comment: Note, you won't always get 0 *in* the array either.

Answer (score 2):

Your array can only hold 10 element, but you attempt to access elements past that.  C doesn't have any kind of bounds checking to ensure you don't do that.  What you get instead is [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), which means you can't predicts how the program will behave.  Note also that the value 0 is just as much garbage as any other value that might be printed.

Also, because `b` is not initialized, the 10 elements it does contain have  indeterminate values.  They could be 0 or they could be something else entirely.  You could also trigger undefined behavior in this case if the values happen to have a trap representation, although you're unlikely to come across that on modern systems.

Comment: You might point that undefined behavior means the program could crash or something worse could even happen such as your bitcoin wallet being erased.